# How can I load JSON into TreeStore?

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, store, treepanel

I would like to load a JSON file into a TreeStore to use in a TreePanel. I can load the store with values and have it display if I hard-code the tree, but when I try to load it from a JSON file it does not display anything in the tree. Here is my code:

JSON file: exampleDoc.json

```
{
    "success": true, 
    "Root": [{
        "name": "Bookmark 1",
        "leaf": true,
        "element": "1"
    }, {
        "name":"Bookmark 2",
        "leaf": true,
        "element": "2"
    }, {
        "name":"Bookmark 3",
        "leaf": true,
        "element": "3"
    }]
}
```

Here is my model

```
Ext.define('bkmark', {
    model: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'element']
});
```

Here is my Tree Store

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'bkmark',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'exampleDoc.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my Tree Panel

```
var treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Bookmarking',
    width: 225,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    region: 'west',
    collapsible: true,
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proxy's `reader` has a config called `root`, which defines where the actual data is when you have top level fields like `success`.

Since your data is under `"Root"`, you should define your reader like so:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'Root'
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the default `root`, which is `data`. So in your json change `"Root"` to `"data"`.

By the way, the standard way to define a model is:

```
Ext.define('bkmark', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : ['name', 'element']
});
```